# Enable solver from Excel VBA avoiding reference problems

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm distributing an Excel file with a Solver model.

In order to avoid Reference problems for certain users of Excel 2007, I'm not enabling the refence in the VBA editor, but modifying the syntax as described in  [this post.](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html#Solver2)

So I'm trying to convert this code:

```
    SolverReset
    SolverOptions Precision:=0.001, MultiStart:=True
    SolverOk SetCell:="$L$5", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$J$2:$L$2", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    solverAdd cellRef:=Range("$K$2:$L$2"), relation:=1, formulaText:=100
    solverAdd cellRef:=Range("$J$2"), relation:=1, formulaText:=2
    solverAdd cellRef:=Range("$J$2:$L$2"), relation:=3, formulaText:=0   
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True, ShowRef:="ShowTrial"
```

Into this one:

```
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverReset"
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverOptions", Precision:=0.001, MultiStart:=True
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverOk", "$L$5", 2, "0", "$J$2:$L$2", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$K$2:$L$2", 1, "100"       
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$J$2", 1, "2"
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$J$2:$L$2", 3, "0"
    Application.Run "SolverSolve", True
```

However, I'm getting compilation errors in lines 2, 4 and 8 in the code above.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use named arguments when passing arguments to `Application.Run` - you'll need to pass then by position.

Comment: Yep - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197132.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that and try to alter the syntax.